# How to make a certain box equal the position of an image HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a regular box like so and an image also:

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<img id="drag1" src="Adho-Mukha-Vrksasana.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

I added JS so that you can drag and drop any image into this particular box

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();

}
function drag(ev){ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
var data= ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
```

I want to run this through a php form so that on the next php it will calculate if the image is in the correct box so that a counter I have will increment (I have several images and several boxes)

ie. `myimageid == boxid counter ++;`

The php will only display how many boxes and picutres the user got correct so that isn't important. The main thing im finding difficult is just saying this image goes into this box

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Are you trying to make the size of the box adjust to the size of the image being dropped in it?

Comment: No. It's for a quiz. I have several images and boxes in my own code and I want to find out if the correct image is in the correct box.

Comment: what makes an image "correct"? What does that have to do with position?

Comment: @chiliNUT I have a piece of text beside each box, this tells the user what box is correct. An example would be I have a picture of a mountain and an ocean. I have two empty boxes like the div above, and beside one box it says mountain and beside the other it says ocean. How would you know if the image of the mountain is in the mountain box and the image of the ocean is in the ocean box. As I've said I'm using php form so i want to say if imageid==boxid (do something).. My trouble is saying imageid==boxid

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you want. On the drop event, you can set the name of the image dropped to a hidden input. Have one hidden input per "box". So, if you drop "image 2" into "box 3", then a hidden input element called "box3" gets the value "image 2". Put those into a form, and submit that. 
So basically:

**JS**

```
function drop {
//your code, and then something like
var id=data; //e.g, "#drag1"
var dropArea=ev.target.id; //e.g, "#drop2";
//just get the number
var number=data.replace(/^[0-9]/g,""); // e.g, "2"
var input=document.querySelector('input[name="box'+number+'"]');//grabs an input called "box2"
input.setAttribute("value", id); //store the fact that we dropped "drag1" input "box2"
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action=someAction.php>
<input type=hidden name=box1 />
<input type=hidden name=box2 />
<input type=hidden name=box3 />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Below is a full working example.

```js
function allowDrop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();

    }
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("id", ev.target.id);
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("name", ev.target.dataset.name);
    }
    function drop(ev) {
        console.log(ev);
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");
        var name = ev.dataTransfer.getData("name");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        updateMapping(ev, data, name);
    }
//maintain a mapping of images<->boxes
    var boxes = ["", "", "", ""];
    function updateMapping(ev, data, name) {
        var boxName = ev.target.dataset.id; //box1
        var boxNumber = parseInt(boxName.replace("box", "")); //1
//remove all instances of data from the array
        prepArray(name);
//add back to the array
        boxes[boxNumber] = name;
//map the array to the form inputs
        updateForm();
    }
    function prepArray(name) {
//remove all instances of data from the array
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            if (boxes[i] === name) {
                boxes[i] = "";
            }
        }
    }
    function updateForm() {
        //apply the array to the form
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                    var boxName = "box" + i;
                    var name = boxes[i];
                    var input = document.querySelector('input[name="' + boxName + '"]')
                    input.setAttribute("value", name);
                }

            }
```

```css
.dropzone, .dragImage{
        width:100px;
        height:142px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
.dropzone{

        border:1px solid black;
    }
.popout:hover{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
 }
```

```html
<!-- boxes -->
<div id="div1" data-id="box1" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div2" data-id="box2" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" data-id="box3" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<hr />
<!-- images -->
<img class="dragImage" data-name="mountain" id="drag1" src="http://i.tcgplayer.com/71491_200w.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img class="dragImage" data-name="island" id="drag2" src="http://i.tcgplayer.com/71485_200w.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img class="dragImage" data-name="swamp" id="drag3" src="http://i.tcgplayer.com/71507.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">

<!-- form -->
<form action="whatever.php">
Box 1:<input type=text name=box1><br />
Box 2:<input type=text name=box2><br />
Box 3:<input type=text name=box3><br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```